# Created my own viewsContainer - can I include views from other viewsContainers?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

We are exploring creating our own viewContainer for VS Code in a new extension and would like to re-use views from other containers, such as the Resources tree, Outline, and others from other extensions. Is this possible?

I was unable to find the view ID for the Outline view, for example, but would hope I could do something like...

```json
"contributes": {
    "viewsContainers": {
        "activitybar": [
            {
                "id": "custom-activity",
                "title": "My Uber-activity",
                "icon": "resources/custom-activity.svg"
            }
        ]
    },
    "views": {
        "custom-activity": [
            {
                "id": "vscode-resources",
                "name": "Resources"
            },
            {
                "id": "vscode-outline",
                "name": "Outline"
            },
            {
                "id": "my-fancy-view",
                "name": "New View"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Is there a list of published IDs for established views in the VS Code environment that we could reference and re-use?

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting question. [According to the sources](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/05fc61ffb1aee9fd19173c32113daed079f9b7bd/src/vs/editor/contrib/documentSymbols/outline.ts#L8), the ID of the outline view is simply `"outline"`:

```ts
export const OutlineViewId = 'outline';
```

Well, ok, let's try that...

```json
"views": {
    "custom-activity": [
        {
            "id": "outline",
            "name": "outline"
        }
    ]
}
```

Ok, let's click our custom view container... oh.

[image]

Erm, yes, I think it's fair to say that this is currently *not* supported. I've reported this as an issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/72453).

Comment: Thank you @Gama11 for testing and reporting that! We'll keep an eye on it.